# Call Restful SFDC service from Java

Tags: oauth2, java, rest

I'm still working on getting the authentication working but having issues.  I have been getting a 401 unauthorized error.  All of the items I have hidden I am sure are correct values UNLESSS I need to add the security token to my password.  Where have I gone wrong so far?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

public class RestWork
{
    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "hidden";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "hidden";
    private static final String URL = "https://cs7.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/hidden/";
    private static final String CONN_URL = "https://cs7.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

    public static void doWork()
    {
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content-type", "application/json"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clientId", CONSUMER_KEY));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clientSecret", CONSUMER_SECRET));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirectUri", "https://localhost:8443/RestTest/oauth/_callback"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("environment", CONN_URL));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));

        StringEntity input = null;
        try
        {
            input = new StringEntity("{\"username\": \"hidden\",\"password\": \"hidden\"}");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(input);

        for (NameValuePair h: nvps)
        {
            httpPost.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
        }

        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println("resp = " + response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out:
resp = HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Date: Fri, 25 Jul 2014 15:59:31 GMT, Set-Cookie: BrowserId=dsfaafffdsfafasd;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Tue, 23-Sep-2014 15:59:31 GMT, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, WWW-Authenticate: Token, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked]}

Comment: You definitely need to add security token to the password.

Comment: Which of these flows [Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) are you aiming to use? I don't see e.g. any grant_type in your request.

Comment: I also see the use of a param called "environment" which I am not used to seeing in integration scenarios, is this how set  endpoint in java?

Comment: Edited answer. @KeithC Added grant_type password.  I don't know if this is correct or not.

Comment: @rao I'm not sure.  I took an example from someone else that had a different rest request working and am trying to adapt it to SFDC.

Comment: @KeithC O yea, and I think its the Username and Password flow, but honestly it doesn't matter.  As long as I can get it to connect and then later on call a REST service I wrote in Apex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending every attribute in Header than you should send all the attributes in a form-data.
This will resolve your issue.

Refer the snapshot from postman crome plugin for a sample request.

[image]

Comment: Happy to help :)