# Make Restful call with Parameters

Tags: oauth2, rest, rest-service

This is essentially part 2 building from my earlier question.
[Call Restful SFDC service from Java](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45150/call-restful-sfdc-service-from-java)

I successfully got my service to authenticate.  I also got my service to successfully call a post when the method has no parameters.  When I try to add parameters to my restful service I get an error returned.

```
@RestResource (urlMapping='/CaseCreate/*')
global with sharing class FileNetRest
{
    @HttpPost
    global static String createCase(String pCode)
    {
        return 'success2';
    }
}
```

[image]

When I make this call, I get an error:

```
[
    {
        "message": "Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value at [line:1, column:3]",
        "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try Content-Type of x-www-form-urlencoded and use the x-www-form-urlencoded button. (What you tell the recipient you are sending and the format you send need to match.)

Comment: @KeithC I get an **unsupported media type** error when I do that.

Comment: OK. So how about Content-Type of application/json and use the raw button to just post `{"pCode": "testing"}` JSON?

Comment: @KeithC  Perfect!  If you would like to place that in an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Just as well I was running out of guesses...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So how about Content-Type of `application/json` and use the raw button to just post `{"pCode": "testing"}` JSON?